# What is the argument "lModel" in mongoose context?

Tags: mongoose, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless-framework

I have a NestJs API using Mongoose that I'm trying to deploy to AWS Lambda using the Serverless framework.  I had problems with the '@hewmen/serverless-plugin-typescript' package getting the project to build so I switched over to serverless-webpack.

The project runs fine locally using serverless-offline, but when I deploy it to AWS it won't start due to this error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the lModel
> (DatabaseConnection, ?). Please make sure that the argument lModel at
> index [1] is available in the MongooseModule context.

Does anyone know exactly what this is?  There aren't any types called "lModel" in my project.  Any additional troubleshooting or logging tips for this kind of project setup are also welcome.

Here is my app.module.ts file if that provides any clues:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_URI'),
        dbName: configService.get<string>('MONGODB_NAME'),
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        connectionFactory: (connection) => {
          connection.plugin((schema) => {
            schema.options.toJSON = {
              virtuals: true,
              versionKey: false,
              transform(doc, ret) {
                ret.id = ret._id;
                delete ret._id;
              },
            };
          });
          return connection;
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    TerminusModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, HealthController],
  providers: [AppService, ConfigService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think "lModel" was just webpack minimizing the variable names.

I had a module where I was importing a mongoose model using `MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync()`.  I needed to add the model class to the providers exports array in that module and then import that module in app.module.ts where I was calling `MongooseModule.forRootAsync()`.